# How can I restrict the status reasons a user can select depending on the current status reason of a case?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am designing a workflow that uses the status reason to route cases to a variety of queues within our organisation.

In order to enforce the process within the workflow (and to reduce the number of status reasons the user needs to select from), I would like to restrict which status reasons can be selected based upon the case's current status reason. We have 12 status reasons.

E.g. I would like to ensure that a if a case is in a "Ready for Report Creation" status reason, users can only set the status reason to "Cancelled", "On Hold" or "Draft Report Completed" - but they should not be able to set the status reason to "Report Approved".

I have given some thought to the issue and the current solution I am considering is to:

1. Hide the status reason field on the case.
2. Create a CRM dialog process, which provides the user with the relevant status reasons to choose from, based upon the current status reason for the case.

Whilst this solution is effective, a lot of configuration is required as a page is required for each status reason - within the CRM dialog process.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to less unwieldy solution to this problem?

NOTE: This is an on-premise installation so we have complete flexibility w.r.t. types of solution we can deploy.

Comment: are there limitations to approach where you manipulate the available status reasons? or do you just not want to write the code?

Comment: No limitiations on the way this is implemented. My primary concern relates to maintainability. The dialog process becomes unwieldy quite quickly. 

Unless a better option is provided, I will probably look at using the js methods suggested by @james using an array to map the valid status reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of ways to do this.

A dialog would certainly give you a codeless option.

If you are happy to use JavaScript, you could add & remove options dynamically using functions like `adoption`, `clearOptions` and `removeOption` from [Xrm.Page.ui Control Methods](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx). Which would give a more fluid user experience.

If you want to enforce the business rules you could also add a plugin which throws exceptions when the wrong status is set, to prevent any data imports or other processes from setting the value incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks @james-wood. I have ended up using the Javascript UI classes. They worked a treat.